# Estimate of the Degree of a Polynomial Approximation of log(x)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I have a homework question asking me to find an estimate for the degree $n$ of a polynomial $P(x)$ that approximates $f(x) = \log(x)$ on $[1,2]$ such that $\sup\limits_{x \in [1,2]} |P(x) - \log(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for $\epsilon \in [0,1]$.

From the Weierstrass approximation theorem (WAT) I know such a polynomial exists, and I am trying to tease something out following a proof using Bernstein polynomials because a hint says I can solve this problem by "evaluating the proof of the WAT."

I get lost trying to set up an inequality like $|B_n(f)(x) - f(x)| \leq $ to start with, and I'm not sure what other way(s) I can approach this using/building off a proof of WAT.

---

As I understand the problem, since smaller and smaller $\epsilon$ imply closer approximations to $f(x)$ on the given interval, certain thresholds of error necessitate the use of higher degree approximations. So given $\epsilon \in [0,1]$, I am asked to find an estimate of $n(\epsilon)$ (not necessarily the best one) such that there always exists an approximation of $f(x) = \log(x)$ by $P(x)$ with degree $n(\epsilon)$ where $\sup\limits_{x \in [1,2]} |P(x) - \log(x)| \leq \epsilon$.

Provided that interpretation is correct, I found [this similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149748/how-do-i-use-weierstrass-approximation-theorem), but the given answer is not clicking for me and I can't apply the explanation because of that.

If anyone can lead me the right way or help me put some tools in my toolbox, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I think your efforts would be well spent in trying to understand that previous Question's [Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3149819/3111).  A basic step will be to discover what function $g(t)$ will work with your problem (to approximate $\log x$ with Bernstein polynomials).  I think it would be expeditious to help you if we can narrow your Question to helping you understand steps in such a previous analysis (as they apply to your problem).

Comment: In that answer, I am actually confused about the initial expression of $B_n(f)(x)$, as I haven't encountered it expressed with $f(\frac{2k -n}{n})$, etc. but rather, I've seen it in the form provided in the wiki link. Following that, I don't quite understand the introduction of $g(2)$ (I guess idk why 2, specifically) or how to find what $g(t)$ works for $log x$. The rest seems straight forward; although with how the question was posed, I was hoping there would be a way to avoid using pmf's, variance, etc. as I don't remember those topics being involved in our studies.

Comment: Okay, that additional context is helpful to preparing an answer for you.